# Xamarin installation and update keep crashing

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, xamarin.android

I am trying desperately to make my Xamarin studio work again. I was on Xamarin studio 5.10.3 and I try to update it to 6.0.2 and it keep crashing , I uninstall everything, delete all the xamarin folder information, delete the key product with regedit, download everything again and again but nothing is working, it is stuck to version 5.10.3 newer version even stable keep giving me the same error message (screenshot in image attachement). thanks in advance guys for your help

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNSGg.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to use Xamarin Studio on Windows if there's a free version of Visual Studio 2015 available? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

Comment: I prefer Xamarin studio to Visual Sudio 2015. I have both installed, but my computer is not a beast, it works with too many lags on VS 2015. Xamarin Studio is lighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could work around this by ensuring the correct items are installed. We highly recommend that you move over to use Visual Studio on Windows instead.

https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6

Here are some things you may need to ensure are installed to see if it resolves your problem even though the FAQ above is saying differently:

1) Ensure you download the correct developer pack: http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html

(**4.5.2** should suffice)

2) Ensure you have MSBuild Tools 2013/2015 Installed

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

However I would recommend just using VS from this point on as noted in the FAQ.

Comment: I have all the requirement installed. I havve VS 2015 intalled with Xamarin features but I prefer Xamarin Studio since it is lighter and have better performance on my PC

Comment: You should be able to find IDE logs here: `Help -> Open Log Directory`. However as mentioned before, you should move over to VS in the future on Windows. You can still use Xamarin Studio on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your screenshot, when Xamarin Studio opens, you see MonoDevelop stuff instead of Xamarin. I had the exact same problem some months ago. I solved it by going to main menu > account and then log out. Then restart and log-in again.

Still not sure if that will work in Windows because it was on a mac in my particular case.

Comment: Probleme solved I just had to delete some folders, restart and reinstall Xamarin Studio. now it works perfectly